# Ajax request subdomain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, subdomain

Is there a way to get ajax requests from http://foobar.com to snatch data from pages such as http://sub1.foobar.com/choco.php ?

It seems subdomain requests are still not allowed via javascript

Comment: They probably will never be, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is not sensitive, you may use JSONP (JSON with Padding) as an alternative.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

Comment: as in import data via <script>? There will be multiple requests to sub1.foobar.com/choco.php from foobar.com . How would i need to tell the javascript on foobar.com to repeatedly import script elements from the subdomain for this to work?

Comment: @jiexi: Frameworks like jQuery include this (include `callback=?` in the URL passed to `$.getJSON`), or without a framework: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

Answer (score 0):

JSONP (as [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26210/andrew-moore) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212635/ajax-request-subdomain/4212665#4212665)) or a [Proxy Script](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) for modern browsers, and wrap the request on the local domain for antique browsers.